# Can I make RelativeDateTimeFormatter display more units such year, month and day?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here's my code:

```
let startDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 5, day: 1)) ?? .now
let endDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2020, month: 6, day: 2)) ?? .now

let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
let relativeDateTimeFormatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
let dateRemainingText = relativeDateTimeFormatter.localizedString(from: dateComponents)
```

`dateRemainingText` is `1 year ago`, while I would like it to be `1 year, 11 months, 1 day ago`, which is more accurate

Can I make RelativeDateTimeFormatter display more units such year, month and day, so that it returns `1 year, 11 months, 1 day ago` instead of `1 year ago`?

Comment: Off topic but the difference is 1 years 10 months and 29 days

Comment: Oh. But that's what returns this code (without "ago"): `let startDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 5, day: 1)) ?? .now
let endDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2020, month: 6, day: 2)) ?? .now

let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
let dateRemainingText2 = DateComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from: dateComponents, unitsStyle: .full)`

Comment: No it doesn't, print `dateComponents`and see for yourself.

Comment: Screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/yHP2EYn

Comment: So the bug/problem is in `dateRemainingText2`,  but not in `dateComponents`.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Or do you think I should submit bug report to Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is `DateComponentsFormatter`

```
let startDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 5, day: 1)) ?? .now
let endDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2020, month: 6, day: 2)) ?? .now

let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .day]
dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .full
var dateRemainingText = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: startDate, to: endDate)!
if dateRemainingText.hasPrefix("-") {
    dateRemainingText = "\(dateRemainingText.dropFirst()) ago"
} else {
    dateRemainingText = "in \(dateRemainingText)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
So I will have to localize (aka translate) "in" and "ago" myself.
Does `dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: startDate, to: endDate)` return localized date?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter): *The formatter takes the current user’s locale and language into account when generating strings*

Comment: @user14119170 yes, you must localize the "in" and "ago" as provided with the string... anyway, struggling with the same thing, but this not the answer